# How to Use Customized fonts on Canvas(3 Questions included inside)

Tags: android

1. How to use Customized fonts on Canvas?
2. I have customized view (PIECHART DRAWN ON CANVAS) on left side of the screen and list view on right  of the screen. When ever I touched on the canvas list view values has to be changed. is it possible. My listview is in Activity A class.And view is in B class.
3. I have piechart with n no of arcs. On tapping on that i have to known which arc is tapped. Is there any formula for it. (Like for rectangle basing on left,top and width hegiht we can check.)

Answer (score 0):

1. In the drawText function in the canvas you have to provide a Paint object. Well the paint object has a function that accepts a typeface and it is called [setTypeface()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setTypeface%28android.graphics.Typeface%29). Look more into that function and its uses and perhaps [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/) and you will see that it is rather straightforward to use any font that you like in Canvas.

My advice would be to make questions 2 and 3 separate questions in their own right and improve your explanation of what you want to happen.